# c# Type exists in both appdata and dll file

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll

Hey I started a college project in college and decided to try working on it at home.

I keep getting the following error however whenever I try to use my Customer class.

> The type 'CustomerBank' exists in both 'C:\Users\Cara\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\atmv1\95e5fad3_shadow\fe1b0109\8108\App_Web_customer.master.cdcab7d2.rnqtqpxh.dll' and 'App_Code'   C:\Users\Cara\Desktop\ATMv1\Customer\CustomerHome.aspx.cs   12  9   C:...\ATMv1\

[image]

I have tried deleting the dll. Using both 2012 and 2015 of visual studio. I even tried renaming Customer to CustomerBank but as you can see it is still giving the error and I am at lost. I also tried it on two separate machines outside of college.

Comment: Did you try with the full path `App_Code.CustomerBank`?

Comment: Yeah, it returns a different error that is
"Error 3 The type or namespace name 'App_Code' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 
"

Answer (score 1):

Close `Visual Studio`, delete files in `release` and `debug` folder of your solution and then reopen `Visual Studio`, then right click on you solution or project in `Solution Explorer` and choose `Clean solution/Project` and then rebuild. all.

**Edit :** If you have a website, first you should close `Visual Studio` then delete VS temporary files(example of location: `C:\Users\Cara\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files`  ) then reopen the VS.

Comment: I am using a website not a solution and I cannot see release or debug in the folder. I also do not have the option to Clean solution/Project when I right click or from the build drop down. Im stumped!

I am also now getting thease errors:
https://i.gyazo.com/0ea12aa30a12cdd4c312f3b2349c8967.png

Comment: I tried that and I still get the same error. When I re-open the website it just populates that temp folder again.